# Compiling error ceres library example program "helloworld"

Tags: c++, computer-vision, ceres-solver

I tried to run Ceres library [program](https://ceres-solver.googlesource.com/ceres-solver/+/master/examples/helloworld.cc) in example using `gcc helloworld.cc`. I checked that all of the libraries are in `/usr/local/lib`. I already installed `glog` and `gflag egien` according to following [instructions](http://ceres-solver.org/building.html#linux). I already tried to give explicit path of libraries.

I think I am having linker error but cannt able to figure out how to resolve it.

```
/tmp/ccTx2jwX.o: In function `main':
helloworld.cc:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `google::InitGoogleLogging(char const*)'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `ceres::Problem::Problem()'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x143): undefined reference to `ceres::Problem::AddResidualBlock(ceres::CostFunction*, ceres::LossFunction*, double*)'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to `ceres::Solver::Summary::Summary()'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to `ceres::Solve(ceres::Solver::Options const&, ceres::Problem*, ceres::Solver::Summary*)'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `ceres::Solver::Summary::BriefReport() const'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `ceres::Problem::~Problem()'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x2cd): undefined reference to `ceres::Problem::~Problem()'
/tmp/ccTx2jwX.o: In function `ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<CostFunctor, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0>::AutoDiffCostFunction(CostFunctor*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC2EPS1_[_ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC5EPS1_]+0xb1): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, google::CheckOpString const&)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC2EPS1_[_ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC5EPS1_]+0xbd): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC2EPS1_[_ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC5EPS1_]+0xe3): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC2EPS1_[_ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC5EPS1_]+0xef): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
/tmp/ccTx2jwX.o: In function `std::string* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x24): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::CheckOpMessageBuilder(char const*)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x4b): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::ForVar2()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x66): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x75): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x89): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
/tmp/ccTx2jwX.o: In function `std::string* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, ceres::DimensionType>(int const&, ceres::DimensionType const&, char const*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x24): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::CheckOpMessageBuilder(char const*)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x4b): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::ForVar2()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x66): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x75): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x89): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
/tmp/ccTx2jwX.o: In function `ceres::internal::AutoDiff<CostFunctor, double, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0>::Differentiate(CostFunctor const&, double const* const*, int, double*, double**)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_[_ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_]+0x9e): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, google::CheckOpString const&)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_[_ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_]+0xad): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_[_ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_]+0xbc): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_[_ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_]+0x324): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
/tmp/ccTx2jwX.o: In function `void ceres::internal::Make1stOrderPerturbation<ceres::Jet<double, 1>, double, 1>(int, double const*, ceres::Jet<double, 1>*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x45): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x56): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x9b): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0xcd): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0xde): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x123): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x1dd): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x1fa): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
/tmp/ccTx2jwX.o: In function `void ceres::internal::Take0thOrderPart<ceres::Jet<double, 1>, double*>(int, ceres::Jet<double, 1> const*, double*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_]+0x45): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_]+0x56): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_]+0x9b): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_]+0xf4): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
/tmp/ccTx2jwX.o: In function `void ceres::internal::Take1stOrderPart<ceres::Jet<double, 1>, double, 0, 1>(int, ceres::Jet<double, 1> const*, double*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0x54): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0x65): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0xb0): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0xe5): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0xf6): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0x141): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0x1f4): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0x211): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `gcc helloworld.cc` - did you actually pass any `-l` options too? For actually linking to the libraries?

Comment: Also, it is better to compile/link C++ programs with g++ instead of gcc. With gcc, you usually need to explicitly pass the C++ runtime library by `-lstdc++` (however your unresolved symbols seem to come from other libraries at the moment). Also note, that the order of the libraries in the command line matters - if one library depends on another one, it should appear first in the command line (the linker resolves the library objects in the order they appear on the command line and skips the translation units which are not referenced yet).

Comment: @Angew yeah I passed them -L option using `gcc -L /usr/local/lib helloworld.cc` and tried to include headerfiles but didnt work

Comment: @rajatV I am not asking about `-L`, specifying library directories. I'm asking about `-l`, actually specifying the *libraries.* That has nothing to do with header files - those are for the compiler. You also need to *link* to the libraries themselves.

Comment: you mean for this command `gcc -L /usr/local/lib/libceres.a -L /usr/local/lib/libglogs.a -L /usr/local/lib/libflags.a  helloworld.cc`

I am not clear what you want to say I has recently start to use Linux

Comment: here are my libraries dir -- `http://imgur.com/I7t9Ex4`

Comment: Pay attention to case. You're passing [`-L` (uppercase el)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options), which specifies *paths* to search for libraries. You should be passing [`-l` (lowercase el)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options), which specifies libraries to link (can be done with absolute path, as you're doing).

Comment: Like you said I used `gcc -l /usr/local/lib/libceres.a -l /usr/local/lib/libglogs.a -l /usr/local/lib/libflags.a helloworld.cc` and I am currently getting error like this

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/local/lib/libceres.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/local/lib/libglogs.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/local/lib/libflags.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: The linker is not finding the glog lib, are you sure you included the correct directory, and have glog installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on debian I compiled it successfully with the command:

```
g++ -I /usr/include/ -I /usr/include/eigen3 -I /usr/include/glog -l glog -l ceres helloworld.cc
```

Comment: Maybe the linker on Debian has gotten more clever, but in principle you need to add the `-l` option *after* the source file that needs that library. Therefore, `helloworld.cc` should come before all `-l` options on the command line.