# Ceres-solver Cmake compilation issues with helloworld.cc

Tags: c++, cmake, ceres-solver

I've been working on implementing ceres-solver. To check that I've done it right, Ive been testing out the helloworld.cc file that is given on the Ceres website. However when I run the program, I get a lengthy error (shown at the bottom)

I've looked through similar stack overflow questions ([Installing ceres-solver on centOS7 and getting helloworld.cc to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57696125/installing-ceres-solver-on-centos7-and-getting-helloworld-cc-to-work)) and I know this error has to do with the CMake List and the links found while compiling. However, I am still a bit confused on how to tell the compiler where to find the headers and the compiled libraries for the solver.
If you could provide any resources on

1. which cmake file I should be messing with (there are a ton in the ceres package)
2. how I can tell the compiler where to find the needed libraries, It would be much appreciated.

I run this command:

```
g++ -I /usr/include/ -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I/usr/include/glog -l glog -l ceres helloworld.cc
```

**details about my environment:**

- Ubuntu 18
- eigen 3.34
- gcc7.5
- ceres 1.14

This is my error:

```
/tmp/cc9ybTzk.o: In function `main':
helloworld.cc:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `google::InitGoogleLogging(char const*)'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `ceres::Problem::Problem()'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `ceres::Problem::AddResidualBlock(ceres::CostFunction*, ceres::LossFunction*, double*)'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x183): undefined reference to `ceres::Solver::Summary::Summary()'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `ceres::Solve(ceres::Solver::Options const&, ceres::Problem*, ceres::Solver::Summary*)'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `ceres::Solver::Summary::BriefReport[abi:cxx11]() const'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x295): undefined reference to `ceres::Problem::~Problem()'
helloworld.cc:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `ceres::Problem::~Problem()'
/tmp/cc9ybTzk.o: In function `ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<CostFunctor, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0>::AutoDiffCostFunction(CostFunctor*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC2EPS1_[_ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC5EPS1_]+0xc7): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, google::CheckOpString const&)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC2EPS1_[_ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC5EPS1_]+0xd3): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC2EPS1_[_ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC5EPS1_]+0xfd): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC2EPS1_[_ZN5ceres20AutoDiffCostFunctionI11CostFunctorLi1ELi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EEC5EPS1_]+0x109): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
/tmp/cc9ybTzk.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x33): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::CheckOpMessageBuilder(char const*)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x5d): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::ForVar2()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x7b): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString[abi:cxx11]()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x8a): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0xad): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
/tmp/cc9ybTzk.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, ceres::DimensionType>(int const&, ceres::DimensionType const&, char const*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x33): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::CheckOpMessageBuilder(char const*)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x5d): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::ForVar2()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x7b): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString[abi:cxx11]()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x8a): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiN5ceres13DimensionTypeEEEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_RKT0_PKc]+0xad): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::~CheckOpMessageBuilder()'
/tmp/cc9ybTzk.o: In function `ceres::internal::AutoDiff<CostFunctor, double, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0>::Differentiate(CostFunctor const&, double const* const*, int, double*, double**)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_[_ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_]+0xb1): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int, google::CheckOpString const&)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_[_ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_]+0xc0): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_[_ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_]+0xcf): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_[_ZN5ceres8internal8AutoDiffI11CostFunctordLi1ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0ELi0EE13DifferentiateERKS2_PKPKdiPdPSA_]+0x3b8): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
/tmp/cc9ybTzk.o: In function `void ceres::internal::Make1stOrderPerturbation<ceres::Jet<double, 1>, double, 1>(int, double const*, ceres::Jet<double, 1>*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x50): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x61): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x9e): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0xcd): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0xde): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x11b): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x1c2): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_[_ZN5ceres8internal24Make1stOrderPerturbationINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi1EEEviPKT0_PT_]+0x1da): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
/tmp/cc9ybTzk.o: In function `void ceres::internal::Take0thOrderPart<ceres::Jet<double, 1>, double*>(int, ceres::Jet<double, 1> const*, double*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_]+0x50): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_]+0x61): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_]+0x9e): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take0thOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEPdEEviPKT_T0_]+0xf0): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
/tmp/cc9ybTzk.o: In function `void ceres::internal::Take1stOrderPart<ceres::Jet<double, 1>, double, 0, 1>(int, ceres::Jet<double, 1> const*, double*)':
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0x50): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0x61): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0x9e): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0xcd): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0xde): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0x11b): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0x1bb): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
helloworld.cc:(.text._ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_[_ZN5ceres8internal16Take1stOrderPartINS_3JetIdLi1EEEdLi0ELi1EEEviPKT_PT0_]+0x1d3): undefined reference to `google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I don't think you need to mess with any of the ceres CMake files.
You probably need to create your own directory somewhere, where you create your own CMakeLists.txt file per, http://ceres-solver.org/installation.html#using-ceres-with-cmake , and then copy the helloworld.cc file in that directory as well